# Python use instance of class in a function in another file

Tags: python, class, instance

I have three files, app.py, server.py and tools.py

the files are quite big in total, so i'll just show excerpts
server.py is basically just flask

app.py looks about like this

```
from server import Server
from tools import Tools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web = Server(Server.defaultMainPage)
    tool = Tools()

    # logic
```

tools.py looks like this

```
class Tools()
    def __init__(self):

        # logic 

    def tools_func(self, args):
        # logic
```

server.py looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
from tools import Tools

class Server:

    # A lot of flask stuff, plus one function:
    def do_smth(self, args):
        # logic

        # here I want to call the tool.tools_func() function
```

The problem is that I create an instance of Tools in app.py. In do_smth() in server.py I want to call the tools_func() from the instance of the class I created in app.py, so `tool.tools_func()`. How do I that?

Comment: Can't you pass the instance of `Tools` to the instance of `Server` by passing it as an argument for its `__init__` method?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal but the instance of Tools will be modified multiple times before the do_smth() function is called

Comment: @Neins Since the instance is mutable, it will be passed to the init method as a reference.

Comment: Does the caller of `do_smth` have the `Tools` instance?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal A reference is passed whether the value is mutable or not.

Comment: If `do_smth` needs an instance of `Tool`, it should be passed as an argument. It should not rely on global variables defined in another module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `tool` instance as argument to `do_smth` function in Server.py and call tools_func like this.

```
def server(self, tool):
    tool.tools_func()
```

And in app.py you can do the following

```
Server.do_smth(tool)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the follwing:

- Create a new method in app.py
- Import this method into server.py
- Call this method from do_smth